# Get only column that are string type in impala sql?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, impala

Is it possible in Impala SQL to fetch only the columns that are in a certain type, in my case its a string.

tried to look on google but didn't find any thing
Cheers

Comment: Without specifying them?

Comment: I need to get the name of the columns!

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL to query the information_schema, construct your SQL statement to include just the columns you want and then execute it